# Incorrect results from max and rank function

Tags: oracle

I am trying to return a row with the latest psi score but my code returns multiple rows and the row that I actually want is returned as the last row on result set. What can I do with this code to resolve the issue.

```
S

ELECT REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,
    COALESCE (MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) AS PSI_SCORE
    --COALESCE(MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE)-39.035024/8.439997 AS PSI XMation


    FROM(

    SELECT
    REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,
    MAX(AA.PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY AA.ARANK) MAX_PSI_OVERALL_SCORE,
    MAX(AA.GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY AA.ARANK) MAX_GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE

    FROM (
    select  
      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY REQUEST_NUM ORDER BY REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT ) ARANK
      ,PARENT_PI_NUMBER,REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,PSI_OVERALL_SCORE,GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT
    from  
       WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F

    -- GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE != '10100' and 
      where PI_CANDIDATE_NUM = '4173093'

    --nd GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE is  null
    ) AA
    --where AA.ARANK=1


    GROUP BY REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
    --ORDER By PARENT_PI_NUMBER,PI_NUMBER,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT;


    )
    BB;

Sample data:

    REQUEST_NUM PI_CANDIDATE_NUM REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT PSI_SCORE
    ----------- ---------------- ------------------------ ---------
                         4639022        
        1655626          4639022 5-Mar-17
        1662401          4639022 8-Mar-17                 22.6
        1662470          4639022 6-Apr-17   
        1662486          4639022 6-Apr-17   
        1662499          4639022 8-Mar-17                 30.3
        1771817          4639022 7-Jun-17                 35.3
        1797323          4639022 24-Jun-17                38.5

My expected results is the last row with a value of 38.5 since has the latest date.
```

Comment: You've asked four related questions now, and you still haven't supplied table definitions, sample data or expected results.

Comment: REQUEST_NUM      PI_CANDIDATE_NUM REEQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_D      PSI_SCORE
 4639022  
1655626 4639022 5-Mar-17 
1662401 4639022 8-Mar-17 22.6
1662470 4639022 6-Apr-17 
1662486 4639022 6-Apr-17 
1662499 4639022 8-Mar-17 30.3
1771817 4639022 7-Jun-17 35.3
1797323 4639022 24-Jun-17 38.5
my expected results is the last  row with a value of  38.5 since has the latest date. The top represent column names, i cant get them to align properly but here is how they align with the data----------------------REQUEST_NUM PI_CANDIDATE_NUM REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT PSI_SCORE. let me know if this helps

Comment: Put that in your question, not in a comment. In any case, if you rank by some date and want the most recent one, change the ORDER BY to read ORDER BY <date_column> **DESC** and then select the row where the rank is 1.

Comment: "Please advise its urgent" is inappropriate on a free web site where you get help from volunteers. If you need urgent help for an important production issue, find paid help.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @mathguy: agreed. You may find it useful to add a boilerplate response to urgent begging; I use several from [this list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/master/sites/stackoverflow.com/questions.md) maintained by SO CVR.

Comment: Alex, i edited my question with results set i am getting, my expected results is the last row with a score of 38.5.

Comment: as for using urgent, i apologize of , didn't mean to sound like i am using peoples  generosity

Comment: So, are you looking to select the most recent row (for a given candidate) where **the score is not null**?

Comment: And what do you want to happen if you have two rows on that latest date - e.g. if the last date was actually 8-Mar-17 when you ran this?

Comment: if i have two rows on same date, i want the top row that has value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. It assumes you input a specific candidate (otherwise the analytic function in the subquery can be modified to get the most recent NON-NULL score for each candidate).

**EDIT**: If you need to retrieve the most recent score for ALL candidates, then: (1) remove the condition that filters on a single candidate in the inner query; (2) add `partition by pi_candidate_num` right after `rank() over (` (after the opening parenthesis) and add a space before `order by ...` (still in the `over(.....)` clause of `rank()`). **\EDIT**

If two NON-NULL scores were achieved ON THE SAME DATE (perhaps that is impossible in your data, but if it is...) then BOTH rows will be returned.

I assumed the candidate number is a NUMBER, so I removed the single quotes in the condition; and I changed the candidate number to match your sample inputs.

The WITH clause is NOT PART OF THE QUERY - remove it before you try the solution.

```
with
  test_data ( request_num, pi_candidate_num, request_last_modified_dt, psi_score ) as (
    select    null, 4639022, null                             , null from dual union all
    select 1655626, 4639022, to_date( '5-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), null from dual union all
    select 1662401, 4639022, to_date( '8-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), 22.6 from dual union all
    select 1662470, 4639022, to_date( '6-Apr-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), null from dual union all
    select 1662486, 4639022, to_date( '6-Apr-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), null from dual union all
    select 1662499, 4639022, to_date( '8-Mar-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), 30.3 from dual union all
    select 1771817, 4639022, to_date( '7-Jun-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), 35.3 from dual union all
    select 1797323, 4639022, to_date('24-Jun-17', 'dd-Mon-rr'), 38.5 from dual
  )
select request_num, pi_candidate_num, request_last_modified_dt, psi_score
from   (
         select t.*, rank() over (order by request_last_modified_dt desc) rn
         from   test_data t
         where  pi_candidate_num = 4639022
           and  psi_score is not null
       )
where  rn = 1
;

REQUEST_NUM PI_CANDIDATE_NUM REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT  PSI_SCORE
----------- ---------------- ------------------------ ----------
    1797323          4639022 24-Jun-17                      38.5
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not feasible since the query is supposed to look through thousands of candidates and just pull the latest score for each candidate based of the date range.

Comment: @JKim - sorry, but **YOUR** attempted query had a hard-coded single candidate for whom you needed the most recent score. I already said in my post it is easy to fix it to work for all candidates (I will edit to show how); "thousands of candidates" is irrelevant. Also, what do you mean by "based on the date range" - there is nothing about a date **range** in your post.

Comment: sorry ignore the date range please.